# Multiple IBM Rhapsody Processes not working in Jenkins Running as Windows Service

Tags: jenkins, rhapsody

We are using Jenkins to automate generate and build of IBM Rhapsody models. We are also using clearcase. When a developer delivers to specific stream, an automated Jenkins job updates a dedicated snapshot view on the build server, and a job starts Rhapsody and opens the project associated with that stream. The job then gets the process id of the rhapsody it has started and then starts a our generate/build tool, which connects to the rhapsody instance using a connection string constructed using the process id. Rhapsody is a COM server and it has a nice API you can use for developing automation tools, and we use that.

There are multiple clearcase ucm projects. Thus, to speed up the builds, when people deliver their work, as long as the delivery is to a different stream, we start a Rhapsody process and perform the build. So, sometimes we need to generate and build different projects in parallel.

The problem is: this works like a charm when we execute jobs at windows command line. It also works in Jenkins when jenkins is started from the command line. We can perform code generation for multiple projects at the same time. However, when we run jenkins as a windows server, the job which first starts can launch rhapsody and the other tool can connect to the started rhapsody, but while this job is running, if another job starts, rhspsody process starts, but immediately exits and the other tool cannot connect to the rhspsody because it has exited.

We first set the OMROOT environment variable, then start Rhapsody using arguments: -hiddenui -noanimaition -cmd=open

Jenkins is running as a service, using a user account from the domain, which is administratior on the machine, and as i mentioned, this user can execute as many parallel jobs as we want from directly from command line and from a jenkins which is started from the command line (not running as service)

After days of trying, we could not find why... Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, Rhapsody uses one license for each instance, also for an instance started on commandline. 
Maybe this causes the error if you start a second instance.

What happens, if you start two code generating instances from the windows commandline?

Comment: the problem only occurs when we run jenkins as a service. When we dont run it as a service, everything is fine. So, I think that the problem is not about licence. It is also ok when we start multiple rhapsody processes from the windows command line

Comment: Did you see anything the windows event log?

Comment: I don't remember if we checked the event log. I will try to reproduce the error and check the event log. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar problems when we used Rhapsody in our Jenkins build server including ClearCase.

The easier one was that ClearCase supported only 255 characters in path names. So including the files system structure of Jenkins and the VOB name of ClearCase the whole path of some Rhapsody packages was to long and the job stopped. Took some time to figure that out.

The second problem was running Rhapsody inside a windows service. Your are not allowed to open any window in a service. So starting Rhapsody is now way. Instead you need to use the RhapsodyCli (Command Line Interface) commands to achieve this. There is a PDF in the installation of Rhapsody explaining this. 
Sometimes we had the problem that our RhapsodyCli process didn't stop. So over time all our Rhapsody Licences were used up and we needed to stop the process by hand.

I hope this gives you some hint where to search.

Comment: Thank you for the information. When jenkins is running as a service, the job that we execute runs Rhapsody by providing a command line switch which hides the application window. Therefore, it already executes in "no window" mode. We cannot use the RhapsodyCli, because we need to connect to the application using the COM API with our tools for automated modeling tasks during the job. The CLI application does not support COM applications.